# What does the notation $GL_{2}^{+}(\mathbb{R})$ mean?

Tags: notation

What does the notation $GL_{2}^{+}(\mathbb{R})$ mean? The only part I do not recognize is the $+$ sign. Does it mean the elements of the general linear group with positive entries? Thanks!

Comment: I would say with positive determinant.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Thanks, this also crossed my mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ has two components: one with positive determinants, and one with negative determinants.  The superscript + means you want the ones with positive determinants.